# How do I make mousedrag inside Panel move form window c++/CLR?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clr

I have this System::Windows::Forms::Panel that I want to enable so that if the user click and drags the mouse drags the window around to.

Can I do this? Do i have to implement multiple events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should try to call [Control.MouseDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown?view=net-5.0) and [Control.MouseMove Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove?view=net-5.0)

Here is my code, I suggest you could refer to :

```
    Point pt;

    private: System::Void panel1_MouseDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) 
    {
    
        Point mouseDownLocation = Point(e->X, e->Y);
        pt = Cursor->Position;

    }
    private: System::Void panel1_MouseMove(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) 
    {

        if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
        {
            int px = Cursor->Position.X - pt.X;
            int py = Cursor->Position.Y - pt.Y;
    
            panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(panel1->Location.X + px, panel1->Location.Y + py);

            pt = Cursor->Position;
        }
```